# setLayoutParams() method doesn't work

Tags: android, view, layoutparams

I am making a code that changes its size according to the screen size its application provides. It gets the entire width and height(or its appropriate view's w and h) by onSizeChanged() and onDraw() methods of View.

It worked well in another code however now it shows an error message whenever I tried to put command 'setLayoutParams()' Would you please help me to figure out this problem? The setLayoutParams() actually does not work anywhere in the code. Below is the main class code.

```
public class ManipulateDesign extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private ScrollView sv;
    private TextView tv;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
        tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setText("You're in the first ScrollView\n" +
                "- Living Universe \n" +
                "Wish (upon a star) Hope to (be again)\n" +
                "The one you find, when all is done and through!\n" +
                "If all, made a wish to save, the star would it be in vain?\n" +
                "So much it holds, too dear to part, many ways to see the light of answers!\n" +
                "For all was once, just taken away, that one hope all disappeared so none can break nor brittle my heart\n" +
                "no, never again, until the end");

        sv.addView(tv);
        ChangeSizeView csv = new ChangeSizeView(getApplicationContext());
        ll.addView(csv);
    }

    class ChangeSizeView extends View{
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;

        public ChangeSizeView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            newWidth = w;
            newHeight = h;
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // THIS COMMAND MAKES AN ERROR(not just in this method but anywhere in the entire code) BUT WORKED WELL IN ANOTHER CODE     
            sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (newHeight - 100)));         

            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    >
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the logcat logo that shows error messages

```
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:355)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-11 06:39:52.148: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error, for example post LogCat output please?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'll upload it right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should fully qualify which `LayoutParams` you need, since it is contained in a `LinearLayout`, you need to use `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike. It actually shows no more error but now my scrollView is blinking. Would you help me little bit more please?

Comment: Well the blinking may arise since `onDraw()` is called everytime the screen is redrawn (quite a few times a second ;) and it always calculates the `sv` height and width new... Move the `sv.setLayoutParams(...)` to another place, for example in the onSizeChanged method, so that it is only set once after its size updated.

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much for your quick and correct answer, Michael! I'll mark this as the answer, now!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding ;) But be sure to thoroughly test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had used `LinearLayoutCompat` in xml. But in the code i reached the params by using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams`. so when i changed it to `LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams` it worked as expected.